# Discord JS, how to not allow user to execute a command while answering another command's question, unless it's finished

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So, I have these two (kind of messy) commands.

Here are the codes, though their content doesn't really matter (I guess so):

This one is a find the hidden ball inside the boxes game.

```
client.on("message", async message => {
if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  const { MessageCollector } = require("discord.js-collector");

  function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
  }

  const rndInt = randomIntFromInterval(1, 5)
  console.log(rndInt)

  let answerBox = "";

  if (command === "b" || command === "box") {
      const user = message.author.id
     switch(rndInt) {
      case 1:
        answerBox = 1;
        break;
      case 2:
        answerBox = 2;
        break;
      case 3:
        answerBox = 3;
        break;
      case 4:
        answerBox = 1;
        break;
      case 5:
        answerBox = 2;
        break;
      default:
        message.channel.send("ERROR: If you received this message, please contact the support.");
    };

    message.channel.send(`A ball is hidden under the boxes below!! 
    :gift: ── :one: 
    :gift: ── :two: 
    :gift: ── :three:`);

const botMessage = await message.channel.send(`<@${user}>, Type how many coins you wanna bet.`);
const userMessage = await MessageCollector.asyncQuestion({
  botMessage,
  user: message.author.id,
});
let coinsBet = userMessage.content;

if (coinsTotal < coinsBet) {
    await message.channel.send("You don't have enough coins to bet.");
  } else if (isNaN(coinsBet) == false) {
  const botMessage = await message.channel.send("Type which box do you think the ball is (1, 2 or 3).");
  const userMessage = await MessageCollector.asyncQuestion({
    botMessage,
  user: message.author.id
});

    let bet = userMessage.content;
    if (userMessage.content == answerBox) {
    await message.reply("You got it right and won double the coins!");
    coinsTotal += coinsBet * 2;
  } else if (isNaN(bet) == true || bet >= 4) {
      await message.channel.send("That wasn't a valid input, please type =b ou =box.");
      } else {
    await message.reply(`You got it wrong and lost all the coins which you bet. The right answer was ${answerBox}.`);
    coinsTotal -= coinsBet;
  }
} else {
  await message.channel.send("That wasn't a valid input, please type =b ou =box.");
}
  };
});
```

And this other one opens up a store:

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === "store") {
    message.channel.send(`╭⋟────────────────────────╮
    ──•~ Type the product code (number) to buy it.

    ✦✧✦✧ STORE
    » 1 - Green Seed: 0 coins.


    ╰────────────────────────⋞`)
   message.channel.awaitMessages(m => m.author.id == message.author.id,
    {max: 1, time: 10000}).then(collected => {
        if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() == '1') {
            message.reply(`You bought 1 "Green seed" with success!`);
            seedGreen++;
            seedTotal++;
    }

    else
            message.reply(`Something happened, and it wasn't possible to complete your order..`);   
    }).catch(() => {
            message.reply('Your order was cancelled due to lack of response.');
    });
  };

});
```

Notice how none of that is actually connected to a database, but that's not the point. Thing is, everything is actually working without any issues, except one thing.
In the store code, if an user type "=b" or "=box" instead of "1" or another wrong answer, the bot starts the box game, and whenever an user answers the box game questions with "=store", it also starts the store code.
I tried to figure out how to prevent this from happening, once I created a "let isActive = false" variable on top of the code, and set it to true whenever the bot started the store or box code, and set to false when it was finished, so I could put (&& isActive === false) at the first if of those codes and let them execute only if they are "inactive" (not doing any event I coded).
But it was all in vain, it didn't really work, so I'm pretty much stuck here, and I would gladly accept any kind of help to overcome this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this issue. Here's one that I thought out: At the beginning of the script, you can provide some sort of state prop to the client. I called it `userState` and set it to a Collection:

```js
client.userState = new Discord.Collection();
```

Then whenever a user starts a multi-step command that you don't want them to execute while still in the command, you can set that user's id to some descriptive state, e.g. `"boxGame"`:

```js
client.userState.set(message.author.id, "boxGame");
```

And whenever you need to check if they're in a multi-step command, you can check with:

```js
client.userState.get(message.author.id);
```

Which will either return `"boxGame"` or `undefined`, and you can easily differentiate between them to stop them or let them execute a command, for example, using a switch statement:

```js
if (client.userState.has(message.author.id)) {
  const state = client.userState.get(message.author.id);
  switch (state) {
    case "boxGame":
      message.channel.send("you have to complete the box game first bro");
      break;
    default:
      message.channel.send("You're doing something, finish that something first!");
  }
}
```

And when they complete the box game, you can

```js
client.userState.delete(message.author.id);
```

to clear their state.

Edit: Just reminding you again that this is only one solution on how to solve it, and there are probably better solutions to this than mine.